# Square table cell in a table view

Tags: swift, tableview, tablecell

Instead of having table cells that takes the entire width of the screen, I would like to have square table cell, so that I can have maybe 3 or 4 table cells per line. The table cell would also change its size on the vertical dimension.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UICollectionView instead of UITableView.

Comment: Thanks, can I have access to databases the same way as tableview ?

Comment: @IlanskyNaftali, UICollectionView methods are very similar to UITableView's. Just read this tutorial, it will help you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started.